# How to change data in UICollectionViewCell's?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reusability

In the application I'm currently working on, I need to use several different UICollectionViewCells. The question is, how to correctly implement cells in which, depending on the tab selected in the top menu, it will change how it looks and have different input and output data? [This is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGWxH.png). [And example of cell on another tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hioNR.png).

Here is the code:

DataModel:

```
enum Category: Int, CustomStringConvertible, CaseIterable {
    case places = 0
    case routes
    case events
    case garbagePoints

   ...
  
}

struct ExploreCardData {
    let cardNameTitle: String
    let category: Category
    let cardPlacesImage: UIImage?
    let cardLocationName: String
    let cardLocationIcon: UIImage?
    let cardTransportIcon: UIImage?
    let cardTransportLabel: String
    let cardBeautyIcon: UIImage?
    let cardBeautyLabel: String
    let cardPollutionIcon: UIImage?
    let cardPollutionLabel: String
}

var exploreCardData: [ExploreCardData] {
    var myExploreCardData: [ExploreCardData] = []
    
    myExploreCardData.append(ExploreCardData(cardNameTitle: "Name", category: .places, cardPlacesImage: UIImage(named: "NoImage")!, cardLocationName: "Locality", cardLocationIcon: UIImage(named: "locationIcon")!, cardTransportIcon: UIImage(named: "transportIcon")!, cardTransportLabel: "0,0", cardBeautyIcon: UIImage(named: "beautyIcon")!, cardBeautyLabel: "0,0", cardPollutionIcon: UIImage(named: "pollutionIcon")!, cardPollutionLabel: "0,0"))

    myExploreCardData.append(ExploreCardData(cardNameTitle: "Name", category: .routes, cardPlacesImage: UIImage(named: "NoImage")!, cardLocationName: "Start/Finish", cardLocationIcon: UIImage(named: "locationIcon")!, cardTransportIcon: UIImage(named: "transportIcon")!, cardTransportLabel: "0,0", cardBeautyIcon: UIImage(named: "beautyIcon")!, cardBeautyLabel: "0,0", cardPollutionIcon: UIImage(named: "pollutionIcon")!, cardPollutionLabel: "0,0"))

    myExploreCardData.append(ExploreCardData(cardNameTitle: "Name", category: .events, cardPlacesImage: UIImage(named: "NoImage")!, cardLocationName: "Locality", cardLocationIcon: UIImage(named: "locationIcon"), cardTransportIcon: UIImage(named: ""), cardTransportLabel: "0,0", cardBeautyIcon: UIImage(named: ""), cardBeautyLabel: "0,0", cardPollutionIcon: UIImage(named: ""), cardPollutionLabel: "0,0"))

    myExploreCardData.append(ExploreCardData(cardNameTitle: "Name", category: .garbagePoints, cardPlacesImage: UIImage(named: "NoImage")!, cardLocationName: "Locality", cardLocationIcon: UIImage(named: "locationIcon")!, cardTransportIcon: UIImage(named: "transportIcon")!, cardTransportLabel: "0,0", cardBeautyIcon: UIImage(named: "beautyIcon")!, cardBeautyLabel: "0,0", cardPollutionIcon: UIImage(named: "pollutionIcon")!, cardPollutionLabel: "0,0"))


    return myExploreCardData
}
```

View Controller:

```
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        cv.backgroundColor = .none
        return cv
    }()
    
    var selectedCategory: Category = .places

    var offersForSelectedCategory: [ExploreCardData] {
        return exploreCardData.filter { $0.category == selectedCategory }.sorted { $0.cardNameTitle < $1.cardNameTitle }
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setup()
        layout()
        loadData()
    }

extension ScrollableTabBarViewController: ScrollableTabViewDelegate {
    
    /// When tab is tapped reload data.
    func scrollableTabView(_ tabView: ScrollableTabView, didTapTabAt index: Int) {

        guard index < Category.allCases.count else { return }
        selectedCategory = Category.allCases.filter { $0.rawValue == index }.first!

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ScrollableTabBarViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return offersForSelectedCategory.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let offer = offersForSelectedCategory[indexPath.row]
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell()}

        cell.cardPlacesImage.image = offer.cardPlacesImage
        cell.cardNameTitle.text = offer.cardNameTitle
        cell.cardLocationName.text = offer.cardLocationName
        cell.cardLocationIcon.image = offer.cardLocationIcon
        cell.cardTransportIcon.image = offer.cardTransportIcon
        cell.cardTransportLabel.text = offer.cardTransportLabel
        cell.cardBeautyIcon.image = offer.cardBeautyIcon
        cell.cardBeautyLabel.text = offer.cardBeautyLabel
        cell.cardPollutionIcon.image = offer.cardPollutionIcon
        cell.cardPollutionLabel.text = offer.cardPollutionLabel

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I would change the model so that it was a dictionary of `[Category:[ExploreCardData]]`. Then you can use the `selectedCategory` to get the required array. This will be more efficient than constantly filtering the array.  In your `cellForItem` you need to use something like a `switch` statement to return the required cell type. Also,  you may as well force cast the cell in this code. It is better to crash during development and fix the problem than to just return an empty cell.

Comment: @Paulw11 tnx for answer. But how I can implement this? I should switch by indexPath in cellForItem?

Comment: No, you would switch by the `category` property of the item